# Nav Bar icon can't be pressed with Grid+ CardView

Tags: android, gridview, navbar, cardview

I have the following problem: I have introduced in a standard lateral navigation activity ( the one from the templates) a gird + `CardView`.
On a single item, I have the modify data option that launches another activity. After I introduced the gird + card view the item doesn't work anymore.

I will paste the `XML` here:

**the Main XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_courses"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_courses"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_courses_drawer"
    />


<!--Start of my core -->


<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:padding="40dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <TextView
                android:text="Me"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="Family"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <TextView
                android:text="Calendars"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <TextView
                android:text="Calendars"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




</GridLayout>

<!--end of core -->
```

The Navigation activity I suppose everyone has it. The only modification I have made is :

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_edit_account) {

        //TODO create functionality for account management
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ModifyUser .class);
        intent.putExtra("message",message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

To mention: deleting all the grid + card view data in main xm`, the item works perfectly

Comment: You should have only one main content `View` in your `DrawerLayout`, with the drawer - your `NavigationView` - listed after it. The `GridView` needs to be in the `app_bar_courses` layout somewhere.

Comment: @MikeM. Ty Mike for the answer. Resolved it. Future note, it has a `<include layout="@layout/content_courses"/>` inside `app_bar_courses`, in my example, where the personal `xml` is supposed to be